# Can't create object properties in strict mode

Tags: javascript, mode, strict

If I use strict mode the following code does not work.  It fails on the this.bar = 'foobar'; line.  Why is this so?  How can I make an object property in strict mode?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
"use strict";
var foo = (function () {
    this.bar = 'foobar';
    return this;
}());
alert(foo.bar);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit:**
Thanks to James Allardice for pointing out the problem.
I was erroneously thinking that the self executing function was creating an object but it isn't.  I needed to do one of the following instead:

```
"use strict";
var foo = new function () {
    this.bar = 'foobar';
};
alert(foo.bar);
```

or (this one JSLint likes better)

```
"use strict";
var foo = (function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.bar = 'foobar';
    return obj;
}());
alert(foo.bar);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In strict mode, `this` will not refer to the window. In your example, removing the strict mode directive will cause `this` to refer to window.

Since in strict mode, `this` in your example is `undefined`, you get an error. That's because you can't set properties on something that is `undefined`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) (emphasis on the parts relevant to your situation):

> First, the value passed as this to a function in strict mode isn't
>   boxed into an object. For a **normal function**, this is always an object:
>   the provided object if called with an object-valued this; the value,
>   boxed, if called with a Boolean, string, or number this; or **the global
>   object if called with an undefined or null** this...
>   Automatic boxing is a performance cost, but exposing the global object in browsers is a security hazard, because the global object provides access to functionality "secure" JavaScript environments must restrict. Thus for a strict mode function, **the specified this is used unchanged**

Comment: Should this not refer to the anonymous function?

Comment: No. If you run that out of strict mode `this` will refer to the window. The value of `this` depends on how a function is called.

Comment: Also worth reading: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/ Search for the heading: "Eliminates this coercion".